# Error pushing kaniko build image to azure container registry from jenkins groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, azure-devops, jenkins-groovy, azure-aks

I have a scenario, I run my Jenkins in K8s cluster in Minikube. I run a groovy script within my Jenkins Pipeline which builds the docker image
using **Kaniko** (which builds a docker image without docker daemon) and pushes to Azure container registry. I have created secret to authenticate to Azure.

But when I push an image - I get an error

```
 " [36mINFO[0m[0004] Taking snapshot of files...                  
[36mINFO[0m[0004] ENTRYPOINT ["jenkins-slave"]                 
error pushing image: failed to push to destination Testimage.azurecr.io/test:latest: unexpected end of JSON input
[Pipeline] }"
```

My Script

```
My groovy script -- 

def label = "kaniko-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(name: 'kaniko', label: label, yaml: """
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kaniko
    image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command:
    - /busybox/cat
    tty: true
    volumeMounts:
      - name: jenkins-pv
        mountPath: /root
  volumes:
  - name: jenkins-pv
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: pass
          items:
            - key: .dockerconfigjson
              path: .docker/config.json
"""
  ) {

  node(label) {
    stage('Build with Kaniko') {
      git 'https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-jnlp-slave.git'
      container(name: 'kaniko', shell: '/busybox/sh') {
          sh '''#!/busybox/sh
          /kaniko/executor -f `pwd`/Dockerfile -c `pwd` --skip-tls-verify --destination=testimage.azurecr.io/test:latest
          '''
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Could you please help how to overcome the error? And also :

- How do I know the name of the image build by kaiko?
- I m just pushing like - registry.acr.io/**test**: latest, probably it's an incorrect image name that's the reason I get JSON output error?

Comment: I m able to fix it ! :)

Comment: You can add an answer to help others who also find this as you!

Comment: @user2153844 can you provide the answer?

Comment: @user2153844 Could you please tell us how you fixed it?

Answer (score 2):

```
Here is whole procedure.

1. Create ACR Secret

ACR_NAME=youruniquename.azurecr.io
 
# Aenter code heressumes ACR Admin Account is enabled
 
ACR_UNAME=$(az acr credential show -n $ACR_NAME --query="username" -o tsv)
ACR_PASSWD=$(az acr credential show -n $ACR_NAME --query="passwords[0].value" -o tsv)
 
kubectl create secret docker-registry acr-secret \
  --docker-server=$ACR_NAME \
  --docker-username=$ACR_UNAME \
  --docker-password=$ACR_PASSWD \
  --docker-email=ignorethis@email.com
 
  2. Below is jenkins pipeline file for Kaniko
 
podTemplate(yaml: '''
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: maven
        image: maven:3.8.1-jdk-8
        command:
        - sleep
        args:
        - 99d
      - name: kaniko
        image: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        command:
        - sleep
        args: 
        - 9999999
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kaniko-secret
          mountPath: /kaniko/.docker
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - name: kaniko-secret
        secret: 
          secretName: acr-secret
          items:
            - key: .dockerconfigjson
              path: config.json
''') {
    environment {
        APP_NAME = "kaniko-build"
        RELEASE = "1.0.0"
        DOCKER_USER = "acruser"
        DOCKER_PASS = "acr-password"
        IMAGE_NAME = "${DOCKER_USER}" + "/" + "${APP_NAME}"
        IMAGE_TAG = "${RELEASE}-${BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
  node(POD_LABEL) {
    stage('Get a Maven project') {
      git 'https://github.com/cyrille-leclerc/multi-module-maven-project'
      container('maven') {
        stage('Build a Maven project') {
          sh '''
          mvn clean verify
          '''
        }
      }
    }
 
    stage('Build Java Image') {
      git url: 'https://github.com/scriptcamp/kubernetes-kaniko.git', branch: 'main'    
      container('kaniko') {
        stage('Build an image') {
          sh '''
            /kaniko/executor --dockerfile `pwd`/Dockerfile --context `pwd` --destination=acrrepo.azurecr.io/kaniko-demo:${BUILD_NUMBER}
          '''
        }
      }
    }
 
  }
}
```